# How to enable/disable data encryption using NPS policy editor in Windows Server 2008?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, vpn, nps

I'm configuring VPN users connection policy to my Windows Server 2008 using NPS Policy console. I found how to setup password encryption level:

```
NPS (local) -> Connection Request Policy -> <my VPN policy> -> Settings -> Authentication Methods
```

but can't figure out how to enable/disable data encryption. Could your please advice me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NPS (local) -> Network Policies -> <my VPN policy> -> Settings -> Encryption
```